# Bibtex to create an annotated bibliography with sections

Tags: bibliographies, bibtex

I am currently working on an annotated bibliography with several dozen references in Bibtex.  I have found a bibtex style, called plain-annote.bst, that allows me to add an annote tag that adds the annotation in the expected location when I compile.  I have been trying to find a way to add sections into the bibliography, so references that are similar are grouped together.  For instance, I want all papers on "Ethics" to be grouped together, and all papers on "Biology" to be grouped together.  Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE.

Comment: The package `multibib` might be helpful.  (I have no personal experience with it, but the documentation looks promising.)

Answer (score 1):

I don't know what kind of output are you looking for, but this could be a solution:

```
% !BIB TS-program = biber
% !BIB program = biber
% !TEX encoding = UTF-8 Unicode
% !TeX TS-program = xelatexmk

\begin{filecontents}{archivio.bib}



@book{Eth1,
    Address = {Rome},
    Publisher={Libreria Editrice Vaticana},
    Author = {Mario Rossi},
    Title = {Something about Ethics},
    Annote = {This is a very nice publication about Ethics This is a very nice publication about Ethics This is a very nice publication about Ethics This is a very nice publication about Ethics This is a very nice publication about Ethics This is a very nice publication about Ethics},
    Year = {2015}}, 

@book{Eth2,
    Address = {Rome},
    Publisher={Libreria Editrice Vaticana},
    Author = {Gino Rossi},
    Title = {Something else about Ethics},
    Annote = {This is another very nice publication about Ethics This is another very nice publication about Ethics This is another very nice publication about Ethics This is another very nice publication about Ethics This is another very nice publication about Ethics This is another very nice publication about Ethics },
    Year = {2015}}, 

@book{Bio1,
    Address = {Rome},
    Publisher={Libreria Editrice Vaticana},
    Author = {Mario Rossi},
    Title = {Something about Biology},
    Annote = {This is a very nice publication about Biology This is a very nice publication about Biology This is a very nice publication about BiologyThis is a very nice publication about BiologyThis is a very nice publication about Biology This is a very nice publication about Biology },
    Year = {2015}},

@book{Bio2,
    Address = {Rome},
    Publisher={Libreria Editrice Vaticana},
    Author = {Pippo Rossi},
    Title = {Something else about Biology},
    Annote = {This is another very nice publication about Biology This is another very nice publication about Biology This is another very nice publication about Biology This is another very nice publication about Biology This is another very nice publication about Biology This is another very nice publication about Biology} , 
    Year = {2015}}  

\end{filecontents}

\documentclass[11pt, openany]{book}
\usepackage[autostyle,italian=guillemets]{csquotes}
\usepackage[style=chicago-notes,
            annotation=on]{biblatex}

 \DeclareBibliographyCategory{Biology}
 \DeclareBibliographyCategory{Ethics}
 \addtocategory{Biology}{Bio1, Bio2}
 \addtocategory{Ethics}{Eth1, Eth2}
\addbibresource{archivio.bib}  

 \begin{document}


 \printbibheading
 \nocite{*}
 \printbibliography[category=Biology,heading=subbibliography,%
                    title={Biology}]
 \printbibliography[category=Ethics,heading=subbibliography,%
                    title={Ethics}]
 \end{document}
```